# Any Method to use master jsp page with multiple actions and invoking partial jsp page into master page in Spring Web MVC Annotations. Any EXAMPLE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, annotations

Spring MVC Annotation:
Please can anyone  tell me that is there any method in spring to display URL in such manner
 ShowTab.do?module=Leads , ShowTab.do?module=Account, ShowTab.do?module=Status.     Means [partial jsp page?common controller=Actions]

for example: zoho crm
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/ShowTab.do?module=Leads
https://crm.zoho.com/crm/ShowTab.do?module=Accounts

CODE: Which gives only  crm/CreateEntity/
Expected output':crm/CreateEntity/module?=Lead   or
crm/CreateEntity/module?=Account

@RequestMapping(value = "/CreateEntity", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Code:
@Controller
public class CreateEntitiesController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/CreateEntity" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView CreateEntity(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("module", "CreateLeadStatus");       
    return new ModelAndView("CreateEntity");

}
```

">Create Entity

Comment: .do?  This isn't Struts.

Comment: yes example is in struts. but i need it in .jsp instead of .do. please help

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/CreateEntity", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String CreateEntity(HttpSession session,ModelMap map) 
 {
  String retVal = "CreateEntity"; 
  
  return retVal;
 }
But its displays only crm/CreateEntity  where i expect as crm/CreateEntity?module=lead

Comment: Too broad.  You should annotate Spring controller methods to handle each operation.  Struts is circa 2000.  You should think about REST, not Struts.

Comment: Sir is it possible to do using Spring web MVC annotations?

Comment: Yes, did you read the docs?  Use a JSP ViewResolver.  My advice would be to forget about duplicating Struts and using JSPs.  Think REST and decoupled services that return JSON or XML.

Comment: But my software is already architected using spring web mvc annotation.

Comment: Please tell me is there any way to disply the respective output using Annotations?

Comment: You can write RESTControllers and annotate them.  If your software is done, why are you here?  You should be able to put any URL you wish into those annotations.  No help from me beyond that.  Good luck.

Comment: What is after the question mark is a query parameter. It will be in the URL is the client sends it, and won't be in the URL if the client doesn't send it. It doesn't have much to do with Spring. If you want this parameter in the URL, why don't you send it?

Comment: By default its should be  somewhat like this:

Comment: https://crm.zoho.com/crm/ShowTab.do?module=Account

Comment: https://crm.zoho.com/crm/ShowTab.do?module=Status

Comment: Is there any solutions using Spring web mvc annotation to display the URL in such maner dear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Controller
public class CreateEntitiesController {

```
@Autowired 
private CreateEntitiesDao createentitiesdao;

  @RequestMapping(value = { "/CreateEntity" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)  
  public ModelAndView CreateEntity(@RequestParam(defaultValue="",required=false)String module,Model model) {  
      model.addAttribute("module", module);  
     // module = module== null ? "": module;
      if(module.equals("leadstatus"))
      {
          model.addAttribute("pgtitle", "Lead Status");
          model.addAttribute("viewpg", "CreateLeadStatus.jsp");
          model.addAttribute("controllername", "Connroller name");
      }
      else if(module.equals("account"))
      {
          model.addAttribute("pgtitle", "Account");
          model.addAttribute("viewpg", "account.jsp");
          model.addAttribute("controllername", "Connroller name");
      }

      return new ModelAndView("CreateEntity");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use param keyword to differentiate the request based on different query parameter

For Example

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/crm/CreateEntity")
public class YourController{

 @RequestMapping(params = ("module=Leads"))
 public ModelAndView method1(){
  //Your code goes here
 }

 @RequestMapping(params = ("module=Account"))
 public ModelAndView method1(){
  //Your code goes here
 }

}
```

Comment: Controller CODE: @RequestMapping(value = "/CreateEntity", method = RequestMethod.GET,params = ("module=LeadStatus"))
 public String CreateEntity(HttpSession session,ModelMap map) 
 {
  String retVal = "CreateEntity"; 
  
  return retVal;
 } JSP CODE: <li><c:url value="/CreateEntity" var="CreateEntity" /> <a data-params='{"module":"LeadStatus"}'
        href="<c:out value='${CreateEntity}'/>">Create Entity</a></li>

Comment: HTTP Status 400 -

type Status report

message

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Its not WORKING SIR

Comment: What is the Http request Url  in address bar when you click Create Entity hyperlink from Client Side?

Comment: HTTP request URL is /CreateEntity.    method name would be "module" and actions would be  "Action 1" , "Action 2" /calling the action onto the partial index page.

Comment: Actually the method is not getting displayed in such format:  EG: CreateEntity?module=action1 where CreateEntity is the whole page name, module is the method and action 1 is the partial page calling onto the CreateEntity page partially

Comment: How to map module=Leads on jsp page:                                                     
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/crm/CreateEntity")
public class YourController{

 @RequestMapping(params = ("module=Leads"))
 public ModelAndView method1(){
  //Your code goes here
 }

 @RequestMapping(params = ("module=Account"))
 public ModelAndView method1(){
  //Your code goes here
 }

}

Comment: Looks like your client side code is not correct. Can you change it in such a way to make url like ''/CreateEntity?module=Leads". You can try @kafkas client side code

Comment: JSP CODE Like:                                                                                       
 <li><c:url value="${contextPath}/crm/CreateEntity" var="CreateEntity" /> <c:param name="module" value="Leads" />
</c:url> <a href="<c:out value='${CreateEntity}'/>">Create Entity</a></li>

Comment: Hi Bharath sir please can you browse  onto the link given below:                                     https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16619148

Comment: Add @RequestParam("module") in front of module argument in CreateEntity method.   Like public ModelAndView CreateEntity(@RequestParam("module") String module,Model model) {

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:8080/user/showFormForEdit?userId=4

```
<!-- construct an "update" link with travek id -->
<c:url var="updateLink" value="${contextPath}/user/showFormForEdit">
   <c:param name="travelId" value="${travel.id}" />
</c:url>

@RequestMapping(value = "/showFormForEdit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showFormForEditUser(@RequestParam("userId") Long theId, Model theModel) {
.....
}
```